# Is there a Stand-alone Touchpad with included tap-to-click functionality? or a way to get Windows Server 2012 to detect a Logitech Touchpad?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, touchpad

I'm currently using a Logitech Wireless Touchpad T650. Out of the box, the touchpad has press-to-click functionality, but not tap-to-click. To give it tap-to-click, it needs software called SetPoint, offered by Logitech. For a few different reasons (I'm using Windows Server 2012 being one of them) I can't use the SetPoint software, it does not detect the unifying receiver that came with the touchpad.

Is there a way to get SetPoint to detect a Logitech USB unifying receiver on Windows Server 2012? My tech guy is expensive, and can't figure it out, so if you have directions I can give him, that would be great. Clearly the above answer would be much easier for me.

Comment: well, setpoint isnt supported on server 2012.  have you tried the compatibility mode troubleshooter?

Comment: I tried...no luck. any other ideas?